# problems to understand the function quantile

Tags: r, quantile

I have an uneven number of observations and I want to combine them into quartiles. For that I have used the function quantile:

```
a <- round(rnorm(187, mean=100, sd=20))
Quartile <- as.integer(cut(a, quantile(a, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE))
```

As expected, there are different number of observations in each quartile. My question is what determines that a observation that is in the limit between, for example, quartile 1 and quartile 2, is finally allocated to quartile 1.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try `?quantile` in the console? R help tends to be very explicit about the details.

Comment: First check this output `Quartile <- cut(a, quantile(a, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE)` quantile is creating the breaks and then cut is assigning values based on that breaks!

Comment: Hi John, yes I try, but I still don't get it

Comment: Is your question about `quantile` or is it about `cut`? It is probably best to first understand e.g. how `quantile(a,1/4)` is computed and see if that answers your question. You should be able to read the algorithm described in the help and implement it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is really about how `cut` functions. See the parameters it takes below.

```
cut(x, breaks, labels = NULL,
    include.lowest = FALSE, right = TRUE, dig.lab = 3,
    ordered_result = FALSE, …)
```

Your question concerns the parameter named "right," which decides whether the interval includes the value on the right or the left of the interval. You can change this parameter depending on what kind of inclusion rule you would like to use. There is no hard and fast rule in statistics on which way to choose; it's up to you, but once you make a decision for any given project, the same method should be used consistently.

I guess to answer your question though, if you are sticking with the default and something falls on the boundary, it will be included in the lower interval.